# Changing the order of widget preview in android

Tags: android

I have developed some a widgets for my app. Whenever i want to place the widget on the screen, i go into the widget menu an look at the specific folder of my app. My widgets appear there and i can select them properly. i was wondering about, whether i can change the order of my widgets in the widget preview. The preview itself doesn't seem to be with an alphabetical order so it has to be configurable somehow, but how?
This is what i mean with: 
[widget preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mOKe.jpg)

Comment: There are hundreds of home screen implementations. You have no way of knowing what order any of them will display your widget previews.

Comment: ok thanks, that's too bad